# Использоваине переменных в транзакциях Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

есть 2 таблицы

```
create table T(id int, vale int)
insert into  T
values
(1, 10),
(2,20)
 -----
create table R(id int, value int)
insert into  R
values
(1, 100),
(2,200)
```

нужно выполнить следующие транзакции

```
         BEGIN  ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
         BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
         SELECT SUM(value) INTO _t2_sum FROM R;
          BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
         SELECT value INTO _t1_value FROM T WHERE id=1;
        SELECT MAX(value) INTO _t3_max FROM T;
         UPDATE T SET value = _t1_value + 50 WHERE id=1;
        COMMIT;
        UPDATE T SET value = _t2_sum WHERE id=1;
        COMMIT;
          UPDATE R SET value = _t3_max + (SELECT MAX(value) FROM T) WHERE id=2;
         COMMIT;
```

В транзакциях используются переменные, насколько я понял в пустом месте их объявить нельзя, только в функции или операторе "Do"

Если так

```
Do
$$
declare 
   t1_value integer;
   t3_value integer;
   t2_value integer;
    Begin
     BEGIN  ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
         BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
         SELECT SUM(value) INTO _t2_sum FROM R;
          BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
         SELECT value INTO _t1_value FROM T WHERE id=1;
        SELECT MAX(value) INTO _t3_max FROM T;
         UPDATE T SET value = _t1_value + 50 WHERE id=1;
        COMMIT;
        UPDATE T SET value = _t2_sum WHERE id=1;
        COMMIT;
          UPDATE R SET value = _t3_max + (SELECT MAX(value) FROM T) WHERE id=2;
         COMMIT;
         End;
         $$
```

то выдает ошибку

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ISOLATION"
LINE 8:      BEGIN  ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
                ^
```

в функции тоже самое.

как можно выполнить данный изначальный  код?

Comment: Судя по всему никак http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274457/set-isolation-level-for-postgresql-stored-procedures

Comment: Тут проблема даже не в переменных, а во вложенных транзакциях. Постгрес так не умеет.